# Pandas subsetting two dataframes based on rows that meet condition in one

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.  One contains a long list of strings in different languages and the other contains labels of the language that the first is in.

```
train_data.head()

string
0   Klement Gottwaldi surnukeha palsameeriti ning ...
1   Sebes, Joseph; Pereira Thomas (1961) (på eng)....
2   भारतीय स्वातन्त्र्य आन्दोलन राष्ट्रीय एवम क्षे...
3   Après lo cort periòde d'establiment a Basilèa,...
4   ถนนเจริญกรุง (อักษรโรมัน: Thanon Charoen Krung...
```

And:

```
labels.head()

language
0   est
1   swe
2   mai
3   oci
4   tha
```

What would be the best way to subset both dataframes to only strings with spanish or english?  Where language in the second dataframe is equal to 'en' or 'es'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join two dataframes such as:

```
joinedDf = train_data.join(labels)
```

then

```
joinedDf[(joinedDf['language'] == 'en' )|(joinedDf['language'] == 'es' )]
```

should get you only the English and Spanish texts.